# countdown.js daily countdown with period of displaying text

Tags: javascript, countdown

I got a countdown js from http://countdownjs.org/ it should:

count towards the next closest 20:00 cest (my timezone)

from 20:00 - 23:00 it should display "Streaming now"

then after the time is up (I don't really mind the one minute between 22:59 and 23:00) it should start counting towards the next closest 20:00 again.

What I have so far is:

```
<script src="js/countdown.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var clock1 = document.getElementById("countdown")
  , tdy = new Date();

  var ahours;
  ahours = tdy.getHours();

if( ahours > 20 && ahours < 23 ) {
    clock1.innerHTML = 'Streaming NOW!';
} else {
  if (
  clock1.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate()) + 1, tdy.getHours(20)).toString();
  setInterval(function(){
    clock1.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate() + 1, tdy.getHours(20)) ).toString();
  }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

But ofter adding the timegrabber and condition to display "streaming now" it is not working. Can you point me in the right direction as to what is wrong?

Comment: The syntax in your `else {}` block is all sorts of messed up. That's me pointing in the right direction. If you're still having trouble I can elaborate when I get to a keyboard.

Comment: Lol, thank you - the thing was working - just had to remove the "if (" line